# Is retrofit post data to api in background thread automatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

Hi all I have question is retrofit post data to api in background thread automatically or should I use something like RXjava to make it?

Comment: Which frame you are using if spring you can use @async in service

Comment: `execute` uses the current thread and `enqueue` uses a background thread and then runs the callback on the calling thread. Or if you're using coroutines, it's most natural to define suspend functions so you can use them synchronously without blocking threads.

Comment: Thanks all for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrofit by default doesn't run network requests on main thread (if thats what you need to know), so you don't really need to do anything in that regard.

but if you are using Kotlin, i would highly suggest you to use Retrofit with [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?gclid=Cj0KCQiA15yNBhDTARIsAGnwe0X2PUnZuMitq9iiTy2e4T8a4LnU_RY5ZxySFrDG9j6Hgfg4XoUC89waAojzEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), which is not mandatory for kotlin applications but it is more efficient and is built in kotlin itself so you don't need to install any third party lib.

here is a useful guide on how to use Retrofit with Coroutines:
[link](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutines-in-android)

Comment: Thanks Bilal .. yes that i want to know... Thanks again